# Can't pull docker image behind a proxy

Tags: image, docker, proxy, pull

I am trying to pull images behind a proxy.

1. I've setted the docker config file : `~/.docker/config.json` :

```
{
 "proxies":
 {
   "default":
   {
     "httpProxy": "...",
     "httpsProxy": "..."
   }
 }
}
```

2. Setted $DOCKER_CONFIG as `[asbolute_path]/my_home/.docker`
3. Restarted docker daemon: `sudo systemctl restart docker`

Not working.

Documentation I followed :

https://docs.docker.com/network/proxy/#configure-the-docker-client

Any tips ?

Comment: what errors are ya getting? please provide a reproducible issue as much as possible

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You referenced to a wrong document, the method mentioned in `configure-the-docker-client` is all about how to set default proxy for containers, not for `docker daemon`, while `docker daemon` is the program who responsible for pull docker image.

The correct step is as next:

1. `mkdir -p /etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d`
2. new a file `/etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d/http-proxy.conf` with something like next:

   ```
   [Service]
   Environment="HTTP_PROXY=http://proxy.example.com:80"
   Environment="HTTPS_PROXY=https://proxy.example.com:443"
   Environment="NO_PROXY=localhost,127.0.0.1,docker-registry.example.com,.corp"
   ```
3. restart the docker daemon with next:

   ```
   systemctl daemon-reload
   systemctl restart docker
   ```

NOTE: above things need be executed with sudo/root.

You should see next after check `docker info` if you are successful:

```
$ docker info | grep Proxy
 HTTP Proxy: http://proxy.example.com:80
 HTTPS Proxy: https://proxy.example.com:443
 No Proxy: localhost,127.0.0.1,docker-registry.example.com,.corp
```

Details refers to [official document](https://docs.docker.com/config/daemon/systemd/).

Comment: still not using proxy...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56200292/7508077