# executor failed running [/bin/sh -c go mod tidy]: exit code: 1

Tags: kubernetes

docker build

```
docker build -t xiongchuanhong/postserver:v3.2 -f ./dockerfiles/postserverDockerfile ./
[+] Building 12.2s (9/10)                                                                                                                                              
 => [internal] load build definition from postserverDockerfile                                                                                                    0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 521B                                                                                                                              0.0s
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                                                                 0.0s
 => => transferring context: 2B                                                                                                                                   0.0s
 => [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/golang:latest                                                                                                  1.7s
 => [1/6] FROM docker.io/library/golang:latest@sha256:02c05351ed076c581854c554fa65cb2eca47b4389fb79a1fc36f21b8df59c24f                                            0.0s
 => [internal] load build context                                                                                                                                 0.0s
 => => transferring context: 55.15kB                                                                                                                              0.0s
 => CACHED [2/6] WORKDIR /go/src/github.com/mygohttp                                                                                                              0.0s
 => [3/6] ADD . /go/src/github.com/mygohttp                                                                                                                       0.0s
 => [4/6] WORKDIR /go/src/github.com/mygohttp/servers/postserver                                                                                                  0.0s
 => ERROR [5/6] RUN go mod tidy                                                                                                                                  10.3s
------
 > [5/6] RUN go mod tidy:
#9 0.225 go: downloading github.com/prometheus/client_golang v1.11.0
#9 0.225 go: downloading google.golang.org/grpc v1.41.0
#9 0.227 go: downloading golang.org/x/net v0.0.0-20200822124328-c89045814202
#9 0.233 go: downloading github.com/golang/protobuf v1.4.3
#9 10.30 ObservableService/servers/postserver imports
#9 10.30        github.com/prometheus/client_golang/prometheus/promhttp: github.com/prometheus/client_golang@v1.11.0: Get "https://proxy.golang.org/github.com/prometheus/client_golang/@v/v1.11.0.zip": net/http: TLS handshake timeout
......
------
executor failed running [/bin/sh -c go mod tidy]: exit code: 1
```

I don't know how to solve it. Does docker need to configure the golang environment in advance?

macOS

This is Dockerfile

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Ea58.png)

This is postserver.yaml

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: postserver
  labels:
    app: postserver
spec:
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      name: postserver
      labels:
        app: postserver
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: postserver
          image: xiongchuanhong/postserver:v1
          imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
          ## 容器内部的端口
          ports:
            - containerPort: 9090
            - containerPort: 8080
      restartPolicy: Always
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: postserver
---
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: postserver
  annotations:
    ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "false"
spec:
  rules:
    - http:
        paths:
          - path: /postserver
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: postserver
                port:
                  number: 9090
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: postserver
  labels:
    svc: postserver
spec:
  selector:
    app: postserver
  ports:
    - targetPort: 9090
      port: 9090
      name: postserver2
    - targetPort: 8080
      port: 8080
      name: postserver
---
apiVersion: monitoring.coreos.com/v1
kind: ServiceMonitor
metadata:
  name: postserver
  labels:
    release: prometheus
spec:
  endpoints:
    - port: postserver
      path: /metrics
      scheme: http
  namespaceSelector:
    matchNames:
      - default
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      svc: postserver
---
```

my run command is docker build -t xiongchuanhong/postserver:v3.2 -f ./dockerfiles/postserverDockerfile ./

The purpose is to build an image file

Comment: Go is failing to download the `promhttp` package due to a `net/http: TLS handshake timeout` error. Potential duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51890390/docker-not-able-to-pull-images-behind-proxy-tls-handshake-timeout

Comment: But I have installed a VPN, it should not be affected by the network

Comment: Please post the related files like Dockerfile, docker-compose.yml here, so that people can validate the issue